# How to increase thread count /parallelism in Azure web applications

Tags: azure

I have one asp.net web app running on Azure. It can receive users REST request, and process the data and send it back.
I have setup Scale up for Azure instances if the CPU percentage goes upto 60%, and Scale down if CPU percentage moves below 40%. 
One thing I observed that, My tasks are most IO bound not CPU intensive tasks. So if the number of request increases then my app is keeping all the requests waiting.

How can I make my App to process 100's of request at once ?

I am observing that my app can process 2 request in parallel, Is there a way to increase this parallelism ?

How to setup Azure Scaling based upon the number of incoming requests.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making sure that you are correctly using async/await in applicable areas. If your web app is performing some long-running operation (such as a database call), you should definitely be using async/await to free up threads to service other requests.

Second, even a small instance should be able to handle more than two requests at a time.

Third, you can set up custom rules to scale your web application on metrics other than CPU utilization. Disk queue length is another metric that you might find useful to scale on.